# Qt Client(GUI) Connection to QT Server

Tags: qt, client-server, qtnetwork

All the examples I have seen till now point me to a client server where a client has just one functionality (ex: get the server date and time) and the server just serves this functionality. So when the Server gets a request from the client it knows what business object's function has to called to serve the request.
But, when building complex applications (ex: a school management system) there are a lot of business objects on the server, now, how does the client tell the server which business object's function to be called.
This whole question is with regard to QT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use customize Signals and Slots for your purpose.

From Client side

Just emit signals with passing parameter as a job id or job name

```
ex: emit signalA(jobId);
```

and at server side, connect the signal to required function

```
ex: connect(client, SIGNAL(signalA(int jobId)), this, SLOT(functionA(int jobId)));
```

I hope this will help you in identifying the job

Comment: This helps thank you. Just clarifying.
If I put the jobID and the function to be called for the job ID in a shared config file which both the server and the client can read from will this help?

Comment: Frankly, i never tried this way. But anyways, give it a try :)

Comment: When I do that I will update the comment here, so people will know how this can help. Thanks